# BLE Scan Started but doesn't find any device

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm trying create a plugin that scan BLE devices for Flutter. I did it in Kotlin and i started scan from Flutter via MethodChannel. I saw results in console on Android 11 but i can't see in Android 12.

I saw this logs in Android 12 :

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=8 mScannerId=0
```

That's my code:

```
//Permissions check
      private fun checkPermissions(binding: ActivityPluginBinding): String {
        if(bluetoothAdapter != null){
          val requiredPermissions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            listOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
          } else {
            listOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)
          }
    
          val missingPermissions = requiredPermissions.filter { permission ->
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
              binding.activity.applicationContext.checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            } else {
              TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
            }
          }
            Log.v("REQPERMISSIONSS",requiredPermissions.toString())
          if (missingPermissions.isEmpty()) {
            return "${bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled}"
          } else {
            Log.v("MISSINGPERMISSIONSS",missingPermissions.toString())
            requestPermissions(binding.activity,  missingPermissions.toTypedArray(), BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
          }
        }
        return ""
      }

//Start scan for BLE Devices
      private fun startBeaconScan() {
        val scanSetting = ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build()
          if (!scanning) {
            scanning = true
            bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null,scanSetting, scanCallBack)
          } else {
            scanning = false
            bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallBack)
          }
        Log.v("ISSCANNING",scanning.toString())
      }

      private val scanCallBack : ScanCallback by lazy {
        object: ScanCallback(){
          override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results)
            Log.v("SCANNER","onScanRESULT $results")
          }
          override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            var device = result?.device
            if(device!=null&& eventSink!=null){
              eventSink!!.success(device)
            }
            Log.v("SCANNER","device name is ${device?.address}")
          }
    
          override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            Log.v("SCANNER","onScanFailed $errorCode")
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Have you updated all your permissions to match the new Android 12 requirements? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Comment: Yes my permissions same like the document.

Comment: Maybe you could show your code where you ask the user for these permissions?

Comment: I'm new in Kotlin, this question can be frustrating but i should learn that. Should i request in runtime and how can i do that?

Comment: @Emil i did an permissionChecker editing my question.

Comment: And do you ever call that new method? Do you get a popup in the app asking the user for premission now?

Comment: Yes i do in MethodChannel. I see the permission dialog when i click startScan button from Flutter side. But now it resolved. I don't know how but it resolved.

Comment: Now my problem is : Ble Scanner doesn't find my beacon. onScan Result return it -> ScanResult{device=0A:CF:D6:D5:8B:4D, scanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=-1, mServiceUuids=null, mServiceSolicitationUuids=[], mManufacturerSpecificData={6=[1, 9, 33, 10, 40, 26, -17, 78, -55, 112, 66, 97, 114, 97, 110]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null, mTransportBlocks=[]], rssi=-53, timestampNanos=1190976478253764, eventType=16, primaryPhy=1, secondaryPhy=0, advertisingSid=255, txPower=127, periodicAdvertisingInterval=0}